# How to serialize list in a formatted way

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a list in a class like

```
public class Root
{
 public List<Sensor> sensorList
 {
    get;set;
 }
}
```

When serializing this class, XML is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <sensorList>
    <Sensor>
      <Channel>1</Channel>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
      <Channel>2</Channel>
    </Sensor>
  </sensorList>
</Root>
```

But i need xml like this

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <Sensor>
      <Channel>1</Channel>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
      <Channel>2</Channel>
    </Sensor>  
</Root>
```

How can i achieve this using list?

Comment: Can you show your serialization code?

Comment: Do you not want to deserialize it back? You may need to create a custom serilization.

Comment: I need to deserialize it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an XmlElement attibute to your `sensorList` property in Root gives you the desired results. Check the code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Root temp = new Root();
        temp.sensorList = new List<Sensor>();
        temp.sensorList.Add(new Sensor() { Channel = "1"});
        temp.sensorList.Add(new Sensor() { Channel = "2" });

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        XDocument mydoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = mydoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            ser.Serialize(writer, temp);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" After serialize :" + mydoc.ToString());

        using (XmlReader reader = mydoc.CreateReader())
        {
            Root newTemp = (Root)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine("After deserialize :" + newTemp.sensorList.Count);
        }
    }
}

public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Sensor")]
    public List<Sensor> sensorList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class Sensor
{
    public string Channel;
}
```